# Proof verification for the $n$th Root Test.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prove the $n$th Root Test: Suppose $x_k \geq 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and suppose $\sqrt[k]{x_k}\to L$ as $k\to\infty$. Then we have the following conclusions.**

I only proved the first part, which states if $L>1$, then the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ must diverge. Here is how I did it:

> Suppose $\sqrt[k]{x_k}\to L$ where $L>1$. Then, there exists
>   $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq N$, $\sqrt[k]{x_k}>r$ where
>   $1<r<L$. Then, it follows that  \begin{align*} x_N &> r^N \\ x_{N+1}
> > &> r^{N+1} \\   &\vdots \\ x_{N+k} &> r^{N+k}   \end{align*}
>
> which implies $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}x_k > \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}r^k$. Since
>   $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}r^k$ is a geometric series with $r>1$, it must be
>   divergent. Then by the comparison test, $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}x_k$ must
>   be also divergent. Thus, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k =
> > \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}x_k+\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}x_k$ is divergent.

Comment: "Then by the comparison test"... comparison of what to what? you only need the fact that once you know $\sqrt[k]{x_k}>r>1$, $x_k\ge \sqrt[k]{x_k}>r>1$ to conclude

Comment: I am comparing $x_k$ to $r^k$. Since $x_k>r^k$  for $k \geq N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, doesn't that mean the series of $r^k$ being divergent imply the series of $x_k$ must be also divergent?

Comment: But you wrote that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \sqrt[k]{x_k}$ must be divergent

Comment: Okay, either way I think that was just a typo, you got the right idea. But from your wording I thought you were saying something along the line of $\sum x_k$ is divergent, so by comparison test $\sum \sqrt[k]{x_k}$ is divergent, which makes no sense in many ways.

Comment: Yes, I realized it was a typo. I am not trying to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[k]{x_k}$ is divergent, I am trying to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ is divergent.

Comment: Just to be clear, with your apparent typo fixed, your proof is correct. For the other side, an almost identical proof works.